# Configuring Angular for Codepen

Tags: angularjs

What am I doing wrong to get started with an angular codepen?

https://codepen.io/TylerL-uxai/pen/mwqNLW

```
    (function () {
      'use strict';

      angular
        .module('timeOff')
        .controller('TimeOffController', TimeOffController);

      TimeOffController.$inject = ['$scope'];

      function TimeOffController($scope) {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass empty dependency array to your module,

```
  angular.module('timeOff',[])
```

**[WORKING CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/sajeetharan/pen/BZmXvY)**

Comment: Nice! The times aren't loading on the drop downs... But angular is working?

Comment: @user6582640 Yes you dont get the module erro anymore

Comment: Any idea how to fix the numbers? Thank you for fixing the module error

Comment: @user6582640 you need to put  <div  ng-controller="TimeOffController as vm" >

Comment: God bless you! Thanks so much!